# In CkEditor, how do I apply a stylesheet while I'm currently editing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ckeditor

When CKEditor is loaded and I'm editing the stuff, I want the background to be yellow as I edit.

How do I "set" that stylesheet inside the editor.

Comment: Can you post your current code on jsfiddle.com and link it?  Or perhaps, take a screenshot pointing to what you want to make yellow?  I was trying to figure out if you meant the textarea, or the toolbars.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an option `contentsCss` which lets you to load an external CSS stylesheet containing your custom style definitions. Using that you can make your content look exactly as it would look on your website. So in order to use it you need to instantiate CKEditor in the following way:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('mytextarea', {
    // Custom stylesheet for the contents
    contentsCss : 'assets/custom.css'
});
```

And you would also define you `custom.css` for example as follows:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #444;
    background-color: yellow;
}

h1, h2 {
    color: #555;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
}

/* etc some custom styles */
```

### EDIT. Using config.js

There are couple of ways to achive what you need using `config.js`  file. Example:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    // ... some other configuration options

    // Define some custom class to be assigned to body element ogf the editor area
    config.bodyClass = 'body-yellow';
};
```

Create `contents.css` file in the same folder as `config.js`. Inside define your styles:

```
.body-yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

That's it.

Comment: can I do this in config.cfg instead of like that?

Comment: The stylesheet parser is useful only to automatically populate the Styles combo with the classes available in your css. Given the stylesheet that you have proposed it won't do anything. The really important part of your answer that does correctly address the question is the use of the contentsCss option to specify the stylesheet that must be applied to the content http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.contentsCss

Comment: @AlfonsoML do you really think I posted my answer without having tested it? This example will work just fine.

Comment: @user847495 Yes you can, in this way it's as well pretty easy. Check my updated answer.

Comment: @dfsq yes, your answer works because you have specified correctly the contentsCss, but the part of your answer that talks about the Style sheet parser plugin isn't needed. Just try that: don't add that plugin and you'll see that the styles are applied to the content just by using contentsCss

Comment: @AlfonsoML Ok, agree. Thanks for clarification, you are right!

Comment: Can I hot-swap the css?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' ); //textarea with id="editor1"
editor.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev ){
    //set the background properties
    this.document.$.childNodes[1].childNodes[1].style.backgroundColor = 'Yellow';
    editor.focus();
});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Create a CSS class that has the background color you want, then use jQuery `.focus();` in an additional javascript in your footer:

```
$('#target').focus(function() {
  $(this).addClass("yellowBG");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go a bit further you can actually define your custom style sheet from your javascript at run time -

```
function generateCSS(){
    var base = document.createElement('style'),
        baseAttributes = {'id': 'yourID', 'type': 'text/css'}, 
        cssString = '';
    base = $(base).attr(baseAttributes);
    //Now create your css rules
    cssString += '.body-yellow {background-color: yellow;}';
    base.append(cssString).appendTo('head');
}
```

And then when you are done with it, you can delete it, if you so desire.

You could of course use plain JavaScript to do this. I used jQuery here just to be concise. This method sort of helps when your plugins virtualise your rows and you don't want to crowd your style sheets with rules that may or may not be used. So when the rows are deleted and inserted (assuming you have quite a lot of custom styling on these rows), you don't need to keep digging through the DOM to re apply the styles -> generate your css and be done with.